# Code igniter Outputting data from cache

Tags: php, caching, codeigniter-2

I have the  following functions in my controller :

```
public function cached_icd10() {
        /*
Get information from database and cache the information         */
        $this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'file'));

        $cacheID = "icd10";
        if (!$cache_data = $this->cache->get($cacheID)) {
            //ge information from the  database 
            $data['icd10_codes'] = $this->icd_10_codes();

            // Save into the cache for 5 minutes
            $this->cache->save($cacheID, $data['icd10_codes'], 300);
            $cache_data = $data['icd10_codes'];
        }
        return $cache_data;

    }

    public function form() {
        //Fetch all ICD10 Codes from the cache file which is icd10

        $cache_data = $this->cached_icd10();


        $this->load->view('form', $cache_data);
    }
```

The first function caches information from the  database and the  second one passes it to the  view called form. When I try to output the information from my view , it fails throwing an error : Message: Undefined variable: cache_data while when I try to do it from the  controller it echoes it very well. Using the  code below :

```
 <?php
    foreach ($cache_data as $value) {
        echo 'Out put per line is ....:    ' . $value['icd_description'] . ' and the  Id is .... ' . $value['id'] . '<br>';
    }
    ?>
```

How can I display this information from my controller to my view ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your cache data to view by using `array`

```
public function form() {
     //Fetch all ICD10 Codes from the cache file which is icd10
        $cache_data = $this->cached_icd10();
        $data['cache_data']=$cache_data;// create and pass data to array
        $this->load->view('form', $data);
    }
```

You can get you cache data in your view with

```
foreach ($cache_data as $value) {
       // your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->driver('cache',
        array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file', 'key_prefix' => 'my_')
);

$this->cache->get('foo'); // Will get the cache entry named 'my_foo'
```

Ref Url : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/caching.html#example-usage